# Add marks and point to polar axes plot in PGF Plots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I try to plot line in polar axes

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,report]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary {calc, patterns, arrows.meta,graphs,shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary {datavisualization.formats.functions, datavisualization.polar}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\tikz \datavisualization [
  scientific polar axes={0 to pi, clean},
  all axes=grid,
  style sheet=vary hue,
  legend=below
  ]
  [visualize as smooth line=sin,
   sin={label in legend={text=$3 \sin{\varphi}$}}]
  data [format=function] {
    var  angle : interval [0:2*pi];
    func radius = 3*sin(\value{angle}r);
  }
  
    [visualize as scatter, style={mark options={scale=1, fill=blue, draw - blue, mark = *, mark size=10pt}}]
    data [format=function] {
    var  angle : interval [0:4*pi];
    func radius = 3*sin(\value{angle}r);
    };
\end{figure}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I should add point of this line at pi/4, and 3pi/4. So, I marker style not change, if I try to set another style markers options.  ***How to solve this problem?***

Comment: Hm, by now you should know that your posted code is insufficient to be copied and compiled. Please add, what's missing. May be a screenshot is also helpful for the reader in a hurry? Thank you

Comment: @MS-SPO

Sorry for my very awful mistake! Code is updated